# GLSL : Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_FragData'

Tags: macos, qt, opengl, glsl

I'm debugging a really big project shading a tree, in that project the author used glsl file to shader the tree, but I have trouble compiling the glsl file:

Here is the error log:

```
compile: code/trees/TreeRender/Shader/Graph40.vert.glsl
    ERROR: 0:4: '' : syntax error: #version
    ERROR: 0:15: 'layout' : syntax error: syntax error
```

the Graph40.vert.glsl:

```
 #version 120 core  //the original file use version 400

#define VERT_POSITION   0
#define VERT_NORMAL     1
#define VERT_COLOR      2
#define VERT_TEXTURE    3

uniform mat4x4 matModel;
uniform mat4x4 matView;
uniform mat4x4 matProjection;

layout(location = VERT_POSITION) in vec4 Position;
layout(location = VERT_NORMAL)   in vec4 Normal;
layout(location = VERT_COLOR)    in vec4 Color;
layout(location = VERT_TEXTURE)  in vec4 Texture;

out vec4 VertPosition;
out vec4 VertNormal;
out vec4 VertColor;
out vec4 VertTexture;

void main()
{      
    VertPosition = Position; 
    VertNormal   = Normal;
    VertColor    = Color;
    VertTexture  = Texture;

    gl_Position = matProjection * matView * matModel * vec4(Position.xyz, 1);
}
```

Another error log:

```
compile: code/trees/TreeRender/Shader/Default.vert.glsl
ERROR: 0:11: 'matModel' : syntax error: syntax error
```

The Default.vert.glsl:

```
#define VERT_POSITION   0
#define VERT_NORMAL     1
#define VERT_COLOR      2
#define VERT_TEXTURE    3

uniform mat4x4 matModel;
uniform mat4x4 matView;
uniform mat4x4 matProjection;

layout(location = VERT_POSITION) in vec4 Position;
layout(location = VERT_NORMAL)   in vec4 Normal;
layout(location = VERT_COLOR)    in vec4 Color;
layout(location = VERT_TEXTURE)  in vec4 Texture;

out vec4 VertPosition;
out vec4 VertNormal;
out vec4 VertColor;
out vec4 VertTexture;

void main()
{      
    VertPosition = Position; 
    VertNormal   = Normal;
    VertColor    = Color;
    VertTexture  = Texture;

    gl_Position = matProjection * matView * matModel * vec4(Position.xyz, 1);
}
```

I tried to google the error, but found no feasible solution.

I use mac osx, xcode 7.0, the OpenGL and glut are all default versions. Glew version is 1.13.0.

Is that because of the version not match with the original version that the author used? Because I checked the original version, he used GLEW 1.9.0 and GLUT 3.7.6.

/////update//////

The original glsl files have:

```
#version 400 core
```

but there will be an error :

```
ERROR: 0:4: '' :  version '400' is not supported
ERROR: 0:4: '' : syntax error: #version
```

so I commented that line. But other errors still there.

I checked my OpenGL version, using OpenGL Extension viewer, it's 4.1 in my mac, but versions older than that are also supported and should work too. But when I change to #version 410 core, it has the same error, saying that 410 is not supported.

///////////update////////////

It turned out that the version mac supported is NOT the version my context using. I printed in my code using GL_VERSION, it's 2.1 I'm using.  Now I have changed into 4.1, according to [this][1]. But there is still errors:

```
trees/TreeRender/Shader/DefaultDepth.frag.glsl
helloERROR: 0:20: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_FragData'
```

the DefaultLight.frag.glsl:

```
#version 400 core


in vec4 VertPosition;
in vec4 VertNormal;
in vec4 VertColor;
in vec4 VertTexture;

uniform vec3 lightPos;

void main()
{
    float moment1 = gl_FragCoord.z;
    float moment2 = moment1 * moment1;

    gl_FragData[0] = vec4(moment1, moment2, 0.0, 1.0);

}
```

Comment: `#version 120` most certainly doesn't have a `core` profile.  If you want to use `core` and `layout` you'll need `#version 150` at a minimum.

Comment: @genpfault I'm sorry that I just changed that, I have the original file that use #version 400 core, but there is still this error. Now I have commented all #version sentences in every glsl file, so the error disappears but the 'layout' error and 'matModel' error is still there.  But I think they are written just fine, and shouldn't cause these errors, must be something wrong with the version or config...

Comment: The absence of a `#version` directive implies `#version 110` which also doesn't support `core` or `layout`.  Might try `#version 150 core`.  Also make sure you're requesting a Core context from the OS.

Comment: Which OpenGL version does your context have?

Comment: @BDL Thanks very much! I printed the version in the context, it's 2.1 I'm using. Now I have upgrade it into 4.1, but there is still error saying that "Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_FragColor'" , this time it shouldn't because of the version problem right?

Comment: gl_FragColor is deprecated since OpenGL 3.2 Core. You have to use your own output variables.

Comment: @BDL Thanks! Now I have changed declared out vec4 FragColor, and please look at my update in the question description, the gl_FragData is also undeclared, then I changed into FragColor too...Then there is no error after that, but I can't get any thing when executing the code, just a white blank window... I have checked the glsl version I'm using, it's 4.10, the original author use 4.00. But I think the two version shouldn't different that much...are they?

Answer (score 2):

Version 120 does not support core profiles (only OpenGL 3.2+)
Layout quallifiers are also only available in OpenGL 3.2+

Comment: Yes, the original file is #version 400 core, but the '#version' itself is an error. Why? Is that because I'm missing some dylib or header files?

Comment: Try validate your problematic shaders using Khronos' [reference compiler][1] and see if it will throw any error message.


  [1]: https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/tools/Reference-Compiler/

Comment: @stonexjr Thanks for your advice, I'm trying to download it, but why this need a username and password?https://cvs.khronos.org/svn/repos/ogl/trunk/ecosystem/public/sdk/tools/glslang/Install

Comment: I've no idea. I downloaded a copy a week ago and it didn't ask for password. I've maintain a copy up here http://vis.cs.ucdavis.edu/~jrxie/tool/glslangValidator.exe

Comment: @stonexjr Sorry I use mac, thanks anyway, I downloaded the source code from github.